# What does this error message mean?

Tags: python-2.7

I get this a lot when working in python, at seemingly random times when running my program.

```
Assertion 't = find_next_time_event(m)' failed at pulse/mainloop.c:741, function calc_next_timeout(). Aborting.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What does it mean, and how can I maybe avoid it?

Comment: Why not show some code, especially around the mentioned line?

Comment: The mentioned code isn't in the user's program. It's in a library being pulled in.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in a library you are using, or a bug in the way you are using it. Given the `pulse/mainloop.c:741` in the error, it seems like you're probably using Pulseaudio, and likely doing something wrong with the way you're using that API.

You probably need to fix the bug in your code (or in pulseaudio, if it's actually a bug there), to avoid the issue.

Comment: My program is not using any sound!

Comment: Well, you are using something that does. Perhaps posting a link to your program's code in the question will help.

Comment: In that case I guess it's the library Pygame. But I don't understand why there would be a problem in connection to pulseaudio, because as I said, I'm not trying to play any sounds. Maybe this question is better suited for stack overflow..